# Calculate the maximum likelihood estimator

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

So I have this question:

The measurement errors made by a measuring device operating under two different conditions, $i=1$ and $i=2$ are Normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma_i^2$  (Assuming independence)

**a**) Based on a simple sample of measurements made under condition $1,$ the measurement errors $x_1, x_2,\ldots,x_n$ were recorded. Similarly under condition 2, measurement errors $y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_m$ were recorded. Write down the combined likelihood in terms of $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$. If  $\sigma_1=\sigma_2$, write down the combined likelihood in terms of $\sigma_1$

This is what I have written so far but I am not sure if it is correct

$$L(\sigma_1,\sigma_2)=\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sigma_1\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{x_i^2}{2\sigma_1^2}\right)\prod_{j=1}^m\frac{1}{\sigma_{2} \sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left(-\frac{y_{j}^2}{2\sigma_{2}^2}\right)$$

And I am not too sure of how to go on from here

**b**)Derive the test statistics for a maximum likelihood ratio test of $H_0$: $\sigma_1 = \sigma_2$ versus $H_1$: $\sigma_1\neq\sigma_2$

The MLE for $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ over the entire parameter space are 
$$\sqrt\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n {x_i}^2}{n}$$ and $$\sqrt\frac{\sum_{j=1}^m {y_j}^2}{m}$$

For this part of the question I worked out the maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) for $\sigma_1$ as 
$$\hat\sigma_1=\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n {x_i}^2 + \sum_{j=1}^m {y_j}^2}{n+m}}$$
I then substituted everything into the formula and got
$$\lambda=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n {x_i}^2 + \sum_{j=1}^m {y_j}^2}{n+m}}}{\sqrt\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n {x_i}^2}{n} + \sqrt\frac{\sum_{j=1}^m {y_j}^2}{m}}$$

But I am not sure how to simplify it further so as to derive the test statistics from it

Comment: Note that $\sigma_{ij}$ should be coded as \sigma_{ij}, not as $\sigma_{i}{_j}.

Comment: Where you have $(x_{ij}-\mu)^2,$ you should have $x_{ij}^2,$ since it was given at the outset that that expected value is $0. \qquad$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I will make a note of that